# mod_rewrite "400 Bad Request" problem

Tags: mod-rewrite

I can't seem to get past a Bad Request error while setting up mod_rewrite.  I've been trying for a while, so here's what I have.

The url I'm trying to access is:

```
gordons.local/brewCalc
```

The page I'd like to see is

```
gordons.local/index.php?page=brewCalc
```

Here's my rewrite rule:

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteLog /var/www/gordons.com/logs/rewrite.log
    RewriteRule ([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

I've used a regex tool, and [this tool](http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/), but no matter what I end up with a page that says:

```
Bad Request

Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Additionally, a 400 Bad Request error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Apache/2.2.12 (Ubuntu) Server at gordons.local Port 80
```

Also, I'm not getting any information in my access, error or rewrite logs.

EDIT: My rewrite rules are in my vhost file. (/etc/apache2/sites-available/gordons.local)

Comment: Can you access index.php directly with mod_rewrite disabled?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

In case anybody ever finds themselves here, my issue was a missing leading slash before the replacement.

```
RewriteRule ([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Should have been

```
RewriteRule ([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Grrrr....

Comment: it smelled the slash lack

Comment: Your effort to come back here and add this solution saved me from insanity. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you see Apache's error.log you would be able to see the actual error. Most likely you are trying to put above rules in .htaccess file and `RewriteLog` is not allowed in .htaccess file. Also your RewriteRule will redirect more than you intend. So if you comment out your `RewriteLog` and have your RewriteRule like this then it should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# request is not for a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# request is not for a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# forward to index.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA,NC,NE]
```

- NC - Ignore case comparison
- NE - Do not encode RHS URI
- QSA - Append existing Query String into new one
- L - Mark it last rule

Comment: I have these settings in my vhosts file, is that a poor place for it?  RewriteLog was created automatically when I restarted apache, and it has rwx permissions set for all users.  Thanks for the negative look ahead tip, I was planning on adding rules once I got the first one working.

Comment: vhosts is probably the right place. Try changing the RewriteRule as I suggested and then tail apache error.log.

Comment: The rule you provided didn't work, but it helped me notice the missing / before the replacement pattern.  Maybe it's needed because I have the rewrite rules in the vhosts file rather than the htaccess file.  Thanks. (+1)

Comment: That's really strange because I properly tested the solution in my .htaccess before posting. Probably Apache behaves differently when same rules are placed in vhosts vs .htaccess. Glad that you got it working eventually.